# Display part of the content data

Tags: django

I have the following template code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">{{ article.title }}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    {{ article.content }} <!--will display the full text-->
  </div>
```

I intend to show the first 200 characters of the content, like:

```
{{ article.content|length=200 }}
```

How to achieve such a constrain on the text.

Comment: Do you want to add dots in case the 200 is not matched? Like `"Some long ar...."`?

Comment: yes, that's cool but seems impossible in template @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: in fact you can emulate `truncatechars` in terms of `slice`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two *template filters* here that are useful: [**`slice`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) and [**`truncatechars`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars).

`slice` limits an iterable (here a string) to a given number, for example:

```
{{ variable | slice:":200" }}
```

whereas `truncatechars` does approximately the same, except that in case the string is longer than the upper bound (here 200), it will slice to the upperbound *minus three*, and add an ellise:

```
{{ variable | truncatechars:"200" }}
```

For a smaller upperbound, to demonstrate the difference, for a string `variable = "foobarqux"` we would get:

```
{{ variable | slice:":6" }}          # foobar
{{ variable | truncatechars:"6" }}   # foo...
```

The two thus differ: the latter gives a textual hint that there is actually more content. Of course it depends on the specific situation which filter suits your needs.

A nice thing is that you can *emulate* `truncatechars` in terms of `slice`:

```
{{ variable | truncatechars:":6" }}
```

is equivalent to:

```
{% if variable|length > 6 %}{{ variable|slice:":3" }}...{% else %}{{ variable }}{% endif %}
```

But it is of course not the most elegant solution: in case you want `truncatechars` behavior, it is better to use the specific filter.

Comment: The last sentence performs like magics. I were planning to rewrite my view to produce a excerpt of the article.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`truncatechars`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) filter:

```
{{ article.content|truncatechars:200 }}
```